# Scrapy - Error in writing files

Tags: python, operating-system, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
from Erowid.items import ErowidItem
import os

class ExperiencesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "experiences"
    allowed_domains = ["www.erowid.org"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.erowid.org/experiences/exp_list.shtml']

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow =('subs/exp_[a-zA-Z]+.shtml')),callback='parse_item', follow = True)

    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow =('subs/exp_[a-zA-Z]+.shtml')), follow = True)    

    ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        filename = str(response.url)[44:-6]
        selectors = response.css('table')
        if not os.path.exists('drugs-%s' % (filename)): ##Make the file
            os.makedirs('drugs-%s' % (filename))
        list_of_experience = selectors.xpath('//table[@class="exp-cat-table"]/tr/td/a/@href').extract()

        for item in list_of_experience:
            request_url = str(item)
            Request(url="http://www.erowid.org" + request_url, callback = 'request_experience')
            def request_experience(self, response):
                selectors = response.css('div')
                for selector in selectors:
                    experience = ErowidItem()
                    experience['Author'] = selector.xpath('//div[@class="author"]/a/text()').extract()
                    experience['Title'] = selector.xpath('//div[@class="title"]/text()').extract()
                    experience['Substance'] = selector.xpath('//div[@class="substance"]/text()').extract()
                    experience['Text'] = selector.xpath("//div[@class = 'report-text-surround']/text()").extract()

                    title = str(experience['Substance']) + " "+ str(experience['Title'])
                    with open(os.path.join('drugs-%s' % (filename), title),"a") as fid:
                        fid.write(str(experience) + "\n")
```

I am trying to use scrapy to scrape data from Erowid and I am trying to format the data such that for each substance I have a file that is named in the form "substance - title of experience".

My rules get my spider to crawl through the list of websites including https://www.erowid.org/experiences/subs/exp_Acacia_confusa.shtml. Then I get all of the links that go to an experience and put that through a second request this time aiming to gather data from the experience.

I intended to store the data in the format noted above which is "substance - title of experience". For each substance, I want to make a directory that is full of files from that page.

My code, however, makes the directories but does not write the files that I want it to.

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation of `scrapy.http.Request`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) -

> **callback (callable)** – the function that will be called with the response of this request (once its downloaded) as its first parameter.

The callback should be the callable function, not its string, also you would need to define the function, before trying to send it as the callback for the `Request` object.

Example -

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
from Erowid.items import ErowidItem
import os

class ExperiencesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "experiences"
    allowed_domains = ["www.erowid.org"]
    start_urls = ['https://www.erowid.org/experiences/exp_list.shtml']

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow =('subs/exp_[a-zA-Z]+.shtml')),callback='parse_item', follow = True)

    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow =('subs/exp_[a-zA-Z]+.shtml')), follow = True)    

    ]

    def request_experience(self, response):
        selectors = response.css('div')
        for selector in selectors:
            experience = ErowidItem()
            experience['Author'] = selector.xpath('//div[@class="author"]/a/text()').extract()
            experience['Title'] = selector.xpath('//div[@class="title"]/text()').extract()
            experience['Substance'] = selector.xpath('//div[@class="substance"]/text()').extract()
            experience['Text'] = selector.xpath("//div[@class = 'report-text-surround']/text()").extract()

            title = str(experience['Substance']) + " "+ str(experience['Title'])
            with open(os.path.join('drugs-%s' % (self.filename), title),"a") as fid:
                fid.write(str(experience) + "\n")

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.filename = str(response.url)[44:-6]
        selectors = response.css('table')
        if not os.path.exists('drugs-%s' % (self.filename)): ##Make the file
            os.makedirs('drugs-%s' % (self.filename))
        list_of_experience = selectors.xpath('//table[@class="exp-cat-table"]/tr/td/a/@href').extract()

        for item in list_of_experience:
            request_url = str(item)
            Request(url="http://www.erowid.org" + request_url, callback = self.request_experience)
```

Comment: I tried something like this before but the problem is that now the variable filename will be undefined in request_experience and it still wont work.

Comment: you can set filename to self and access it from there . Updating my code for that.

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work for me. All it does is make directories but doesn't get the files.

Comment: Can you put a print or something inside the request_experience function and check if it does get printed .

Comment: I added a print experience inside but nothing gets printed

Comment: Maybe the request is not going through , try setting the errback argument to some method , and inside that method print response .

Comment: I added an errback argument to the request and added a print response to it but it isn't printing anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87596/discussion-between-anand-s-kumar-and-david-yi).